# SharePoint 2013 REST API Request Token: The given key was not present in the dictionary

Tags: 2013, list, rest

I am trying to post data to a SharePoint 2013 REST API using Python. I am able to successfully acquire the required `X-RequestDigest` using the method from [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nadeemis/archive/2012/10/23/tip-handling-http-403-forbidden-when-querying-the-search-rest-service-using-the-postquery-method.aspx).

I have already tried solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22159609/how-to-get-request-digest-value-from-provider-hosted-app) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24313806/sharepoint-hosted-app-error-the-given-key-was-not-present-in-the-dictionary).

I can extract the required token every time, but I get this response from the server when I try to use it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<m:code>-1, System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException</m:code>
<m:message xml:lang="en-US">The given key was not present in the dictionary.</m:message>
<m:innererror><m:message>The given key was not present in the dictionary.</m:message>
<m:type>System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException</m:type>
<m:stacktrace>   
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)&#xD;
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.ReadRequestODataObject(ServerStub serverStub, Object entity)&#xD;
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.InvokeMethodWithRequestODataEntry(Object target, ServerStub serverStub, String methodName)&#xD;
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.TryAddEntity(Object entity, ServerStub serverStub, Object&amp; newEntity)&#xD;
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.Process()&#xD;
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.ProcessRequest()&#xD;
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestService.ProcessQuery(Stream inputStream, IList`1 pendingDisposableContainer)</m:stacktrace></m:innererror></m:error>
```

I use the following code:

```
# First, get security token
token_url = "https://example.com/_api/contextinfo"
tr = requests.post(token_url, auth=HttpNtlmAuth(creds[0], creds[1]),verify=False)
tokenRoot = ElementTree.fromstring(tr.content)

# Since the namespace will not be parsed, it is hardcoded into the string
token = tokenRoot.find("{http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices}FormDigestValue").text
print(token)

headers = {'X-RequestDigest': token}
post_url = "https://example.com/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('listname')/items"

payload = {'__metadata': {'type': 'SP.Data.ListName'},'Title': 'test', 'date_observation': '2015-08-10T22:00:00Z'}

r = requests.post(post_url, data=json.dumps(payload), auth=HttpNtlmAuth(creds[0], creds[1]), headers = headers, verify=False)
print(r.status_code)
```

Any ideas whatsoever?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question resolved. The error message is completely misleading. It has nothing to do with the token - the problem lies within the strict POST message format SharePoint is requiring. If you use the following headers for your POST request, everything works fine.

```
headers = {'X-RequestDigest': token,
           'Accept': 'application/json; odata=verbose',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json; odata=verbose',
           'Content-Length': len(json.dumps(payload))}
```

Comment: I've also encountered this issue when I was using "POST" and should have been using "GET".

Answer (score 4):

I came across this error when there was a malformed field in a list.   I found it by using the Developer Dashboard and just making the api call from there.

It showed me that there was a lookup list that it could not open,  and the lookup field had a render error.

Maybe you are in a similar situation?

Comment: This explained my issue, kind of. One of the document libraries in my site collection had a field that caused this error when returned from the REST api.

Comment: My solution was to use the `$Select` filter to limit the number of fields to avoid the "malformed field" aka the field that caused SharePoint to blow up when we requested this field.

`/Items?%24filter=FileRef+eq+%27%2Fsites%2Fspecial-characters%2FLists%2Fcustom_list%2Ffolder%2Fsubfolder%27&%24top=1`
throws the error, until changed to: 
to
`/Items?%24filter=FileRef+eq+%27%2Fsites%2Fspecial-characters%2FLists%2Fcustom_list%2Ffolder%2Fsubfolder%27&%24top=1&%24select=id%2CGUID`