# Keep getting a 400 Bad Request when trying to create a Site via REST API

Tags: rest, site, postback, java-api

I'm quite new to Sharepoint stuff, and currently am trying to interact with the REST API. I have been able to get all kinds of data without much problems by sending GET reuqests, but sending POST requests has not worked so far (unless sending a POST request to get the context info).

Basically I am trying to add a subsite to my existing site, following the examples from https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj164022.aspx#WritingData ("Section: Create a Site with REST") - however I am using Java as my choice of development language.

First I sent a post request to `/_api/contextinfo` to get the formDigestValue. I include this as a header for the variable `"X-RequestDigest"`. Is this correct way of approaching things?

Afterwards I manage to send the following POST request - but constantly get a 400 Bad Request error.

```
******** LOGGING REQUEST ******** 
Request Method: POST 
Request URI: https://<site_url_hidden>/_api/web/webinfos/add 

Request Headers: 
{X-RequestDigest=[0x16B17C7ECCC4A9D9B42B4F91F1518BAB394F9D...<context_info_retrieved_prior_to_post>],
accept=[application/json;odata=verbose], 
content-type=[application/json;odata=verbose],  
Content-Length=[207], 
Authorization=[<OAUTH_STIFF]}

Body: 
{"parameters": {
    "__metadata":{"type":"SP.WebInfoCreationInformation"},
    "url":"RestSubWeb",
    "title":"RestSubWeb",
    "description":"REST created web",
    "language":1033,
    "webTemplate":"STS",
    "useUniquePermissions":false
    }
}
Response Status: 400
```

The request seems to match what the example is showing, as far as I can see... so currently am pretty clueless on what could be wrong.

Appreciate any help, tips, etc...

EDIT: 
The error I get is:

```
"value":"A value was encountered that has a type name that is incompatible with the metadata. 
The value specified its type as 'SP.WebInfoCreationInformation', but the type specified in the metadata is 'SP.WebCreationInformation'."
```

After changing the type to SP.WebCreationInformation I get the following error:

```
,"value":"The property 'language' does not exist on type 'SP.WebCreationInformation'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type."}
```

EDIT2: Seems like the properties are case sensitive. Sending the correct values has now fixed the problem of 400 - Bad request. Now getting a 401 Unauthorized instead.

Thanks,

Comment: Helpful? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/152778/sharepoint-2013-rest-api-request-token-the-given-key-was-not-present-in-the-dic

Comment: Not sure... my headers look correct. I'm getting also a different error. But I'll try the code in the example and see if I can get anywhere with it.

Comment: are you using JS to make these calls?

Comment: No - using Java. But I'll give it a try with JS tomorrow morning just to see if it works or not... at this point I'd be happy just to get a POST request go through. :)

Comment: Did not manage to send requests via JS. Keep getting 403 error and couldn't figure out how to get past it. Got info on error messages when sending via Java - added to original post. Investigation continues.