# What is the json syntax to insert an item to a list?

Tags: 2013, list, rest, json

I'm trying to insert an item to a list and I keep getting bad request so it's probably because my json is wrong?

Here's what my json looks like:

```
{  
   "securit_x00e9_":"test",
   "column":"test",
   "__metadata":{  
      "type":"SP.List"
   },
   "numero":"test",
   "Title":"test"
}
```

`securit_x00e9_` it's because I used this letter: é and apparently when I checked the xml it's translated to `_x00e9_`.

So is this json wrong?

The header and content type is set to `application/json; odata: verbose`. And I require form digest

```
MERGE https://mysite/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('myDelphiTestList') HTTP/1.1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept: application/json; odata=verbose
If-Match: "5"
User-Agent: Mozarella/1.0 (compatible; Indy Library)
X-RequestDigest: 0x7E78B662646D13B263E3B9964C4D5554F0795C67CB99EFB37D7BA8FB2997DB1D748634497241F0F0BDA1AFF887971D1D2CF98E0739AF5E0969D201AEA834BBE2,28 Jul 2016 09:12:52 -0000
Content-Length: 79
Host: mysite
Authorization: Basic eW91cmljdFw2MDEyNzA4NjY6RGV0cm9pdCUxNTM0Mg==

{"column":"test","__metadata":{"type":"SP.List"},"numero":"test","Title":"tes"}
```

Comment: Please post your entire rest call.

Comment: @AakashMorya I only need to know how to construct my Json part ^^

Comment: You will get entire thing here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `JSON` for updating list item should be like this.

```
{ 
"__metadata":{ "type":"SP.Data.YourListNameListItem"},
"securit_x00e9_":"test",
"column":"test",   
"numero":"test",
"Title":"test"
}
```

In `type` you must write "`SP.YourListNameListItem`"

**Update-1:**

Try removing `securit_x00e9_":"test"` line from your `JSON`, if its update then you have to try the `JSON` as

```
 { 
    "__metadata":{ "type":"SP.Data.YourListNameListItem"},
    "_x00e9_":"test",
    "column":"test",   
    "numero":"test",
    "Title":"test"
    }
```

**Update-2 :**

Based on your commented error message

> "The given key was not present in the dictionary"

Your headers should look like this

```
headers = {'X-RequestDigest': token,
           'Accept': 'application/json; odata=verbose',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json; odata=verbose',
           'Content-Length': lengthofbody}
```

We can avoid '`Content-Length`' header. I tried without this header, It worked.

[source](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/152778/sharepoint-2013-rest-api-request-token-the-given-key-was-not-present-in-the-dic)

**Update-3:**

Please ensure that your url should be like

> https://mysite/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('myDelphiTestList')/items(YourItemID)

Also your HTTP Methods should be `POST`

Comment: My list is called "myDelphiTestList" So i tried SP.myDelphiTestListListItem. It still gives a bad request error.

Comment: updated answer. Try with SP.Data.ListnameListItem.

Comment: Same error. Bad request

Comment: Lastly try once with removing your 'security_x00ep_' field from json. If it updates then there might be issue in this field

Comment: It didn't change anything. But i changed some stuff now i have 500 http error "The given key was not present in the dictionnary". I'm starting to believe sharepoint is a pain in the... pinky :D

Comment: There might be problem in your REST call, not in JSON. So if you post your entire REST Code so we can help you in finding the real evil.

Comment: I posted it, it's what i have from fiddler debugger. I Left SP.List. But i tried both of your suggestions. SP.Data... And SP.MylistListItem. Doesn't change anything. And the column with the "x00e9" change nothing aswell

Comment: I don't get your upate2. My content type is set too. In the raw part of fiddler i can see content-type: "application/json; odata=verbose; charset = utf-8".

Comment: Wow so now i'm changing the Title of the list but not inserting items. Haha is my url wrong?

Comment: Please try with this url "mysite/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('myDelphiTestList')/items(5)", please append "https://" in the begining

Comment: YES! That was close, just didn't need the '(5)' and also use http method of POST and not MERGE. And it works now. Thank you for the time taken :) Adapt your answer to these things and i will accept it as an answer cause you partially helped me :)

Comment: Glad to help. Updated answer.